# Decode hex string to string like hex2bin method in PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift

I need to concat binary with string in swift, to do this we should get same result as PHP 'hex2bin' method, I know its strange but we can do this in PHP(and I cant understand what the hell is going on when we are concating binary with string :) ) :

```
$hexbinary = hex2bin('c0e11c7d13b7bf84b83bb5c8a7873c1c')
$concatResult = $hexbinary . '222'
```

I tried to decode hex to string in swift with all the available encodings, but no one has the same result:

```
let decodedHex = String(data: Data(hex: "c0e11c7d13b7bf84b83bb5c8a7873c1c"), encoding: .isoLatin1//Or other possible encodings)
let concatResult = "\(decodedHex)222"
```

Comment: What implementation of `Data(hex:)` are you using?  What encoding is your data in? .utf8? .utf16?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I tested your code in PHP and it basically gives gibberish.  Are you sure that hex data actually encodes a string?

Comment: your hexastring doesn't look like a valid ascii data

Comment: @Paulw11 Data(hex:) implementation is from CryptoSwift library, and hex data is iv of AES, no maybe its not string, but I need to concat it with another string in swift. so  have to decode it as string.

Comment: Data and result doesn't matter, my question is about doing same operation in swift as PHP.

Comment: Ok, but "maybe its not a string but I need to concat it with a string" doesn't make sense.  If it isn't a string then how can you concat it with a string?  Rather than saying I don't get the same result as I get in PHP, explain what result you want.  You probably want an instance of `Data`, not `String`.  Then do you want to add some more bytes to the end of that data?  Swift has strong typing while PHP does not.

Comment: You could just add `323232` to the end of the hex string.

Comment: That's exactly my question @Paulw11 and I know it doesn't make sense but in some way in php it's working and I need to do the same as the written code in php at the question, so if you can help just tell me what can I do that in swift. thanks.

Comment: You need to explain what *output* you want. Since you need an IV, you probably want a `Data` instance. What is the next step after you create `concatResult`? Simply saying "I want to do the same thing as the PHP code" isn't helpful since it simply doesn't translate directly into Swift.